# How to create a Serial Number for total entries?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

Am new to `DynamicReportBuilder` and want to add a new column to list the serial number of the total rows coming from the db.

Currently, I have researched through [ColumnBuilder](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/ar/com/fdvs/dj/domain/builders/ColumnBuilder.html)

but, wasn't able to find a feasible solution. I have tried this for now,

```
ColumnBuilder serialNo = ColumnBuilder.getNew();
serialNo.setTitle("S No.");
serialNo.setWidth(60);
serialNo.setFixedWidth(true);
logger.info(count+" Total Records");//Count is the total no of rows
for (int j=1;j<count;j++) {
    serialNo.setColumnProperty(j+"",String.class.getName(),j+"");
}
dynamicReportBuilder.addColumn(serialNo.build());
```

But the problem with this is, it is only showing the last count in the serial number row. Something like this: 
S. No.

> 3
>  3
>  3
>  3

Comment: No, doubts for now. I am still waiting to try it. Will let you know

Answer (score 1):

If you like to display the **row count** of your datasource the variabile in jasper report is `REPORT_COUNT`, you can us a [`CustomExpression`](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/ar/com/fdvs/dj/domain/builders/ColumnBuilder.html#setCustomExpression(ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.CustomExpression))  to display this as report is filled.

```
serialNo.setCustomExpression(new CustomExpression() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object evaluate(Map fields, Map variables, Map parameters) {
        return (Integer) variables.get("REPORT_COUNT");
    }

    @Override
    public String getClassName() {
        return Integer.class.getName();
    }
});
```

> **NOTE:** Your current code just loops all the rows and changes the
>   `propertyName` and `description` of the column, hence the result is
>   `serialNo.setColumnProperty((count-1)+"",String.class.getName(),(count-1)+"")`