# How to get summary only at the end when using beans?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am setting one bean into a vectorobj to populate the data into my jasper. 
Now when the row ends, I have to set some other values as kind of a summary which is being queried from different table and being set to the same vectorobj with different name. 
Something like this:

> Bean1 : contains row details
> Bean2 : contains summary details

Both the beans are of same object. 
Now, when the PDF gets printed I'm getting all the values repeated. Like,

```
Row1 
Summary
Row2
Summary
```

But, I'm trying to make it like

```
Row1
Row2 
.
.
.
Summary
```

I have tried many things till now but it hadn't worked. 
Do we need to change something in the ireport jrxml or we need to make changes in the code. 
Here's what code view:

```
Bean bean1=new Bean();
Bean bean2=new Bean();
JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = null;
ArrayList<BusDetails> ResArrObj=dbObj1.getDetails(dbSession,RefNo);
for(BusDetails test: ResArrObj)
{
bean1.setId1(test.getId1());
bean1.setId2(test.getId2());
.
.
vectorObj.add(bean1);
}
SummaryObj summarydetails=getFileDetails(fileToMove);
bean2.setFile1(summarydetails.getFile1);
bean2.setFile2(summarydetails.getFile2);
bean2.setFile3(summarydetails.getFile3);

apbssummaryreportbean.setStAPBAmount(summarydetails.getSumAmount());
vectorObj.add(bean2);//being queried from different table with summary details
ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource( vectorObj,false);      
jasperprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(stJasperLocation+stJasperName,map,ds);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperprint,stReportLoc);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the jrxml as source code as well as some screenshots if possible. Otherwise its very hard to help.

Comment: Create another object for the summary, pass in parameters and use in Summary band (if you need a list, you can for example use a subreport in summary)

Comment: You also have this question open, what happen with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871660/how-to-create-a-serial-number-for-total-entries?

Comment: Hi Petter am currently doing the same thing by creating Bean2 and adding it to vectotobj.

Comment: I was not much familiar with the DynamicReports so I opted for an alternate choice and started using ireports